# How can I rebase a commit made by another author without adding myself as the committer?

Tags: git, rebase

Normally, when you rebase another author's commit with git, git adds a `Commit:` header with your name and email address. I have a situation where I don't want this to happen. I want the rebased commit to end up with the same SHA1 as it would have if the original author had done the equivalent rebase him/herself. Is this possible?

Comment: Even if you do this, the new commit will *not* have the same SHA1 as the original commit. The original commit contains: the "tree" containing all the files in your project, as they were at the time of the commit, the author name/email/date, the committer name/email/date, and a reference to the parent commit. When you rebase, you end up with a totally new commit, that just happens to have the same author information and a similar tree, but even if all that were exactly the same, it would have a new parent. So the SHA1 would change.

Comment: Related (at least closely enough that I found this current question on Google while looking for the linked one): https://stackoverflow.com/q/4981126/5419599

Answer (score 34, accepted):

All git commits have a committer field internally; you can see this by typing `git cat-file commit HEAD` immediately after committing something. As such you cannot erase it; you can only make it equal to the author field.

That said, you might be seeing git porcelain showing the commit field because the *datestamp* has changed. It's not possible to predict what someone else would get for the commit datestamp if they were rebasing, obviously, but you can alter it to be equal to the original commit timestamp, at least.

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter 'export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME"; export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL"; export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$GIT_AUTHOR_DATE"; git commit-tree "$@"' -- basecommit..HEAD
```

This will alter commits after basecommit, in the history of HEAD (including HEAD, not including basecommit), making their committer field identical to the author field in all respects. If the original author agrees to do the same thing, then you can get a consistent SHA1.

Comment: John: This is your answer. Go have a look at any commit you've made - you'll see committer information (name, email, date) there, identical to the author information. Not all methods of viewing commits show the committer date by default - try `gitk`, or `git log --pretty=full`. (or `fuller`, or even `raw`)

Comment: This worked flawlessly after a big rebase. I would feel better if it were writter with git filter-repo, though. Any experts out there?

Comment: This answer uses git filter-repo instead of filter-branch: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76183665/418875

Answer (score 8):

Try setting the environment variable `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME` and `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL` when rebasing (maybe also `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE`, too).  (This will effect all commits created now, though.)

Comment: That doesn't work. It makes the value of the `Commit:` header identical to the `Author:` header. I want it removed entirely.

Comment: Make sure to only set those variables for that command to avoid affecting other commits: `GIT_COMMITER_NAME=... ... git rebase ...`. Otherwise just be sure to `unset` them after you're done!

Comment: @John: I think the `Commit:` header would be there always. More exactly, the raw commit has always an `author ...` and a `committer ...` header entry, even if those have the same value. Only some porcelain tools sometimes select to show only one or both. Use `git show-object ...` or `git cat-file -p ...` to see what is in the commit object.

Comment: @John: of course, bdonlan's answer says the same more clearly.

Comment: You're right -- once I set all of GIT_COMMITTER_NAME, GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL, and GIT_COMMITTER_DATE to the appropriate values, the resulting SHA1 comes out the same as if the original author had done the same rebase on that date.

Answer (score 5):

You can preserve the original committer information when rebasing by using **Interactive Rebase** with `instructionFormat`.

In your config file `.gitconfig`, set this:

```
[rebase]
    instructionFormat = %s%nexec GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=\"%cI\" GIT_COMMITTER_NAME=\"%cN\" GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=\"%cE\" git commit --amend --no-edit%n
[alias]
    rb = rebase --interactive
```

**Explanation:**

- `rebase.instructionFormat` - [a configuration for interactive rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt-rebaseinstructionFormat) to give a custom instruction in the to-do file.
- `%s` - the subject of the commit message (the default value of `instructionFormat`).
- `%n` - a line break; can double-up (`%n%n`) to add a blank line for readability.
- `exec` - instructs `git rebase` to execute the rest of the line as a shell command.

  - It can be shortened to `x` (useful if you're using `abbreviateCommands = true`).
- `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=\"%cI\"` - get the commit date in strict ISO 8601 format.
- `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME=\"%cN\"` - get the name of the committer.
- `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=\"%cE\"` - get the email address of the committer.

  - Above two respect `.mailmap` file if any found. To disregard the file, use `%cn` and `%ce` instead.
- `git commit --amend --no-edit` - amend the commit with the above three environment variables, without opening an editor for the commit message.
- `%n` - a line break (to add a blank line for readability in the to-do file; can repeat for more blank lines).
- `alias.rb` - for convenience, an alias is defined to quickly call interactive rebase with `git rb [new base]`

To use it, be sure you're checked out on the branch you wish to rebase, then **run the command** `git rb [new base]` where `[new base]` is the branch or commit-ish on top of which you want to rebase the checked-out branch. (Example: `git rb main`)

An editor will open with the interactive rebase to-do. **Simply close the editor.** If you know what you're doing and want to edit it, note the following:

- You can see the output of the above config in the file as an `exec` line below each commit.
- If you move a commit (changing the order of commits), be sure to move the corresponding `exec` line as well.
- If you squash, fixup or drop commits, be sure to delete the corresponding `exec` lines.

**Note 1:** This is only possible via Interactive Rebase, since the regular rebase doesn't support `instructionFormat`. You have to bear with the editor opening for no good reason, and just close it (if you have no plans to edit it).

**Note 2:** Even if you preserve all of the committer information, you may still not get the same SHA1 because the SHA1 is dependent on the parent commit. When the parent changes, the SHA1 changes too. However, if the parent didn't change, you will always get the same SHA1. So this is a deterministic operation.

**Note 3:** For Windows, you need to use Git Bash or WSL2. This won't work in Command Prompt and PowerShell since DOS doesn't support inline environment variables. *(I'm not sure if multiple `exec` lines with `SET` commands can work. YMMV but it's so much easier to just use Git Bash or WSL2 than trying to make it work in DOS.)*

Comment: Thank you very much! Using this `instuctionFormat` I was able to rebase while keeping committer names, emails and dates intact instead of overriding them all with a single value! (I also had some `fixup!` commits, which I autosquashed during the rebase, but I was able to delete the extra `exec` lines that would've amended the wrong information, as it was an interactive rebase anyway.)

Comment: @Isti115 ah yes, if you fixup, squash or drop commit, be sure to remove the corresponding `exec` line.