# Git rebase preserve committer

Tags: git, rebase

Obviously when a rebase occurs, it's possible for the committer information to change. What's the best way to preserve committer information (user.name, user.email) on a rebase?

I've tried getting the committer information with `git log -1 --format="%cn` and `git log -1 --format=%ce`, then setting that to my user.name/user.email and rebasing. That should be good enough right or am I missing something?

Comment: Your proposed solution is what I would have done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  I assume you're doing this to make a branch or set of commits look identical to another branch or set of commits.  Rebasing will not create brand new commits since they're done at different times with a different committer.  The SHA-1 hashes won't be the same unless you make everything (including metadata) identical to the original commits - and if you wanted to do that then you might as well use the original commits and not the rebased ones.  So I don't think rebasing will get you what you need.  After a brief google search, it seems like what you're trying to do isn't easily done, and probably for good reason.  That would be my answer - don't do what you're trying to do, I don't know what benefit this would have.

If you still want to investigate, I'd look into [Environment Variables](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables) where you can set `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME` and `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL`, though I'm not exactly sure if you can easily set these on a commit-by-commit basis during rebase.

Comment: I see. It has to do with continuous integration automation. It's a bit of a lengthy discussion to elaborate, but the information you gave me is helpful. Thankfully the original author name persists though.

Answer (score 5):

You can first do the rebase like normal and then use git filter-repo in a second run to set the committer of each commit to that commit's author:

```
git filter-repo --commit-callback '
    commit.committer_name = commit.author_name;
    commit.committer_email = commit.author_email;'
```

It is also possible to use git filter-branch for this task though this is discouraged and much much slower than git filter-repo:

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter '
    GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME";
    GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL";
    git commit-tree "$@"' HEAD
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To clarify, would the `git filter-repo` command above apply to all commits on the branch or just the ones recently affected by the rebase operation? If all, how to limit it to a range `commit_hash..HEAD`?

Comment: @A.L. Yes, by default it would rewrite all commits in the repo. To limit the range of commits according to the [git-filter-repo documentation](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html), the `--refs commit_hash..HEAD` option can be used.

Answer (score 4):

I have a similar problem.  Our core code repository has grown too big, so I've used git filter-branch to break it up, but this creates lots of empty merge commits in the smaller repositories.  In attempting to remove them I found git rebase messes up the COMMITTER_DATE and COMMITTER_NAME/EMAIL which means any branches I rebase, no-longer link back in to the commits they came from, even if nothing changed, which means I can get lots of branches, with identical commits that aren't the same any more.

What seems to be the case is that by accident or design, `git rebase` is not the answer if you want to preserve all three `GIT_COMMITTER` environment variables in commits, use `git filter-branch` instead (which seems to essentially allow you to rewrite commits exactly, only changing the 1 thing mentioned in the commit).  Sadly not as easy as `git rebase -i`

In my case, I'm trying to remove specific commits from history in a branch, or re-order commits.