# git rebase issue reordering

Tags: git, github, git-rebase

I'm having an issue while rebasing git commits. The problem is:

```
pick A
pick B <- mine
pick C 
pick D
pick E <- mine
pick F <- mine
```

I want to squash all my commits into one. I planned to do something like:

```
pick A
pick C 
pick D
pick B <- mine
squash E <- mine
squash F <- mine
```

But that didn't work because if I execute this `git rebase`, the commmit A, C and D would be mine as well. If I just delete the lines from A to D, leaving just:

```
pick B <- mine
squash E <- mine
squash F <- mine
```

the commits A, C and D will be deleted. How can I handle this?

Thanks

Comment: “because if I execute this git rebase, the commmit A, C and D would be mine as well” No, that shouldn’t be the case. You'll be their committer, but not author.

Comment: But I think for a PR on a OS project it would be a little weird to be committer on something you didn't work on, right?

Comment: Not really. Committer isn’t particularly important information, and if you’re rewriting commits, there’s not much point pretending you didn’t. In this particular case, you can rebase off `A` instead and save one change (because you’re not changing it), though.

Comment: Another issue that I've seen is: In github I see that the last 3 commits are mine (B, E, F). Also it is the same for git log. But when I use `git rebase -i HEAD~3`, my commits are not in the same order as `git log`.

Comment: rebase displays commits from oldest to newest. The log is the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [How can I rebase a commit made by another author without adding myself as the committer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5520496/6309), you could try and change the `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME`/`EMAIL` variables, but that would apply to *all* commits rebased.

Another approach is to perform your rebase, then complete it with a [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) to change only `A`, `C` and `D`.

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter \
  'export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME"; \
   export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL"; \
   export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$GIT_AUTHOR_DATE"; \
   git commit-tree "$@"' -- D..HEAD
```