# How to get the author of the last commit in Git?

Tags: git, author

How to get the author of the latest commit in a Git repository?

```bash
#!/bin/bash

git_log=`git ls-remote git url  master`
git_commitId = git_log | cut -d " " -f1
echo $git_commitId

cd /workspace
git_log_verify = `git rev-parse HEAD`
echo $git_log_verify

if $git_commitId =$git_log_verify then
    cd /workspace
    git_authorName=`git log --pretty=format:"%an"`;
    echo $git_authorName
fi
```

Answer (score 117):

This is what you're looking for:

```
git log -1 --pretty=format:'%an'
```

Comment: And if you need this for a script or variable, just add the `xargs` such as.
`git log -1 --pretty=format:'%an' | xargs `

Comment: Where do you get all the escape codes from?

Comment: @minseong you can get them from this [git log#format](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats) link (scroll down a little and you'll see them all)

Answer (score 38):

Or to retrieve the author's email, instead of name:

```
git log -1 --pretty=format:'%ae'
```

Answer (score 21):

To get **author name**:

```
git log -1 --pretty=format:'%an'
```

To get **author email**:

```
git log -1 --pretty=format:'%ae'
```

Answer (score 3):

how to assign  to variable in Groovy:

```
def builtBy = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git log -n 1 --pretty=format:'%an'").trim()
```

Comment: in jenkins declarative pipeline you have to double %%:  (win)  `def builtBy = bat (returnStdout: true, script: "git log -n 1 --pretty=format:'%%an'").trim()     println buildBy`