# Github Push Not Appearing As Contribution

Tags: git, github

Could someone please guide me on whether this is due to incorrect settings or something else.

Whenever I push my changes from the GitHub Desktop GUI app, it does not appear as a contribution on my profile. However if I take the same code and paste it to github via web browser it appears as a contribution.

How do I make it so desktop pushes appear as a contribution as well?

Thank you

Comment: Is it possible that you did not actually push a commit from GitHub desktop?  I doubt there is a problem with Git, more likely with your setup.

Comment: Hey Tim, I meant contribution sorry not commit, have fixed the post to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickly, I see some plausible causes.

1- Commits pushed on a branch other than master may not appear in your contributions.

2- You forgot to commit before pushing.

3- The author's email is set up with a spelling mistake.
There is how to fix the previous commits if it's the third option: [Change git email for previous commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34850831/change-git-email-for-previous-commits)

Comment: Thank you so much, number three was what made it work for me!