# author not mapped to bitbucket user

Tags: git, mapping, bitbucket

I am having a trouble with old repository in bitbucket which is: for all my old commit before 2018 I receive this error message

[image]
the point is it is me who pushed those commits. is there any way that I can map those commits to my account? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

That means the author settings (`git config user.name` and `git config user.email`) was incorrect for those past commits.

You would need to [change the email on past commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34863275/6309) (as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31669789/6309)) and then force push that branch back to your remote repo, in order for those commits to be associated to your account.
If you are the only one working on that repository, this can be done without any adverse consequences.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you don't have to [rewrite history](https://www.google.com/search?q=git+rebase+bad+practice) (which will, among other things, break all current [tags](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging), or at least knock them off-branch) if you just [file your old e-mail address as an "alias"](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-email-aliases/).

> To add an email alias:
>
> 1. Select the **Settings** cog ⚙️ on the top navigation bar.
> 2. Select **Personal Bitbucket settings** from the **Settings** dropdown menu.
> 3. Select **Email aliases** under **General**.
> 4. From the **Email aliases** page, enter your email address in the **Enter email address** field.
> 5. Click Add.
>
> To remove an email alias, click the **x** icon to the left of the alias.