# How to credit contributions to another account for github?

Tags: git, github

Today I was working with my partner on a small project and saved regularly to github using my username and password (https://github.com/mikestepanov/W2D3). Unfortunately we forgot to change global username and because of that our work was credited to the different account.

Since I am the creator/host of the repository, can I somehow credit commits to one of us for that specific repository?

Comment: It is a duplicate, I've found my answer there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to edit past commits (this is called [rebasing](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)) on your local (stored on your computer) git repository, then force-push it to GitHub with a `git push --force` to overwrite the commits on your remote repository.

As for the editing part, you may be interested in [`filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch). [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981126/how-to-amend-several-commits-in-git-to-change-author) gives a nice example that is related to what you aim to do.