# Git contributions not showing up on GitHub

Tags: git, github

I went through your following article https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/ for contribution not being shown on my profile.

To say the least.

- I am pushing commits on my own repository  master branch and I can
  see those commits on GitHub but they aren’t being added in my
  contribution.
- Its been more than 24 hours and in multiple directories.   No, None
  of the repository I am pushing my commits are forked.
- They are no contributors to the given repository so I can push
  commits.

**[Question:]** Can someone tell me what wrong I could be doing? or how to fix it?

My git repository is: https://github.com/irohitb

Example: Consider this repository -> https://github.com/irohitb/Crypto, Here it says last commit was pushed 4 days ago but in my contribution, it doesn't show any contribution which I did in past week

Comment: besides everything that's been already said in the answers, note that the chart only shows commits made to the DEFAULT branch

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check your `git config user.name` and `git config user.email`.

Your user.name should be `irohitb`, after your [GitHub account](https://github.com/irohitb).

The commit of the repo you mention ([commit 0733750](https://github.com/irohitb/Crypto/commit/07337501f6ac72a1df29c9ffdef8d13e05ef2873)) shows:

> Rohit Bhatia authored and Rohit Bhatia committed 4 days ago

In both instances, GitHub does not show a link to `github.com/irohitb`, which means the user.name or user.email didn't match the login/email of your GitHub account.

You would need to [change the author of your past commits](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/) to rectify the situation.
See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4982271/6309).

Answer (score 2):

GitHub uses *only* the commiter's email-address to determine their "identity".

If you use multiple email addresses, you can add all of them on [GitHub's Setting page](https://github.com/settings/emails).

Note, that you have to validate each email address you want to add: so you really can only add valid (as in: they are accepted by a public mailserver) email addresses. an address like `<Rohit@Rohits-MacBook-Pro.local>` cannot be validated, so you can't add it (and you should use `git config user.email` to set a valid email-address instead.)

*PRO tip*: you `git config --global user.email` to set your user-email for all repositories not just the one you are currently working with (a repository-local configuration will override the global settings).

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, the git configuration on your computer might have the wrong email address. In my case it was, for some reason, set to the computer name so wasn't even an email. To check this, go to a commit that is not showing in the graph and add ".patch" to the end of the URL. This will show you the email address of the committer.

To change the author info on your commits, you can follow this [help article on github](https://help.github.com/en/articles/changing-author-info). It has a script that will rewrite the history of all your commits and fix the author/committer info.

From the article:

> Warning: This action is destructive to your repository's history. If you're collaborating on a repository with others, it's considered bad practice to rewrite published history. You should only do this in an emergency.

Any collaborators will have to fetch the new history.

> Note: Running this script rewrites history for all repository collaborators. After completing these steps, any person with forks or clones must fetch the rewritten history and rebase any local changes into the rewritten history.

Steps from the article:

1. Create a fresh bare clone `git clone --bare https://github.com/user/repo.git`
2. Copy and paste the script, replacing the following variables based on the information you gathered:

   OLD_EMAIL
   CORRECT_NAME
   CORRECT_EMAIL

```
    git filter-branch --env-filter '

    OLD_EMAIL="your-old-email@example.com"
    CORRECT_NAME="Your Correct Name"
    CORRECT_EMAIL="your-correct-email@example.com"

    if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
    then
        export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
        export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
    fi
    if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
    then
        export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
        export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
    fi
    ' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
```

Comment: Using .patch was very helpful. I'm setting up a macbook pro and my primary dev machine is a mac mini. When setting up the new machine's git config, I used just my username, which was incorrect (e.g, *Not* the email address associated with my user  GitHub). Once I updated `user.email` to the correct email (which is masked, I used the masked address, same as my normal commits from my primary machine), my profile started registering the activity once again, didn't have to worry about anything else. Thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 1):

Just do it again:

git config --global user.name "usuario"

git config --global user.email "email@email.com"

simple like that... happens to me once...