# Write a shell script or Python code with default arguments for git-filter-repo

Tags: bash, git, shell, command-line-arguments

Sometimes, I need to change the author/committer email and name (assume author=committer always) for all commits in a repository. I need to do this once for repo, but I may need to do it for multiple repos. I'm using this great answer:

[How to amend several commits in Git to change author](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981126/how-to-amend-several-commits-in-git-to-change-author/69947947#69947947)

```
git filter-repo --commit-callback '
    if commit.author_email == b"incorrect@email":
        commit.author_email = b"correct@email" 
        commit.author_name = b"Correct Name"
        commit.committer_email = b"correct@email" 
        commit.committer_name = b"Correct Name"
'
```

However, every time I want to run this command for a new repository, I need to manually change `incorrect@email`, `correct@email` and `Correct Name` in the command above. I want to put this in a shell script, which:

- accepts arguments `old_email`, `new_email` and `author`.
- has default values for these arguments, if one or more is not passed
- if a different argument is passed, it generates an error

How can I do that?

EDIT: I cooked up a preliminary implementation, but it doesn't work:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define default values for email and name
old_email="incorrect@email"
new_email="correct@email"
new_name="Correct Name"

# Parse named arguments with getopts
while getopts ":o:n:e:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    o) old_email="$OPTARG" ;;
    n) new_name="$OPTARG" ;;
    e) new_email="$OPTARG" ;;
    \?) echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2; exit 1 ;;
  esac
done

# Shift arguments to remove processed options
shift $((OPTIND-1))

# Check if any remaining arguments (unexpected)
if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
  echo "Unexpected arguments provided." >&2
  exit 1
fi

# Construct the filter command using here-string
filter_cmd=$(cat << EOF '
if commit.author_email == b"$old_email":
  commit.author_email = b"$new_email"
  commit.author_name = b"$new_name"
  commit.committer_email = b"$new_email"
  commit.committer_name = b"$new_name"
'
EOF
)

# Run git filter-repo with the constructed command
echo "git filter-repo --commit-callback "$filter_cmd""
git filter-repo --commit-callback "$filter_cmd"

# Run git log to confirm that filtering worked
git log
```

Running this in a git repository gives me:

```
cat: ''$'\n''if commit.author_email == b"$old_email":'$'\n''  commit.author_email = b"$new_email"'$'\n''  commit.author_name = b"$new_name"'$'\n''  commit.committer_email = b"$new_email"'$'\n''  commit.committer_name = b"$new_name"'$'\n': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this all in one shot by using `elif` and `else` in the callback, as demonstrated in the `git-filter-repo` [documentation examples](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/Documentation/git-filter-repo.txt#L1122), like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------
git-filter-repo --filename-callback '
  if commit.author_email == b"incorrect1@email"
    # change it
  elif commit.author_email == b"incorrect2@email"
    # change it
  else:
    # put default here
  '
--------------------------------------------------
```

Add additional swaps in `elif` blocks and the default in the `else` block.

**Side Note:** In the example in your question, you are setting both the Author and Committer based on the Author alone. Perhaps they are always the same in your repo in which case it doesn't matter. If they do ever differ though, you may wish to handle them separately.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't get it. I'd like a script which can be called with args `old_mail`, `new_mail`, `author`: if I don't pass one or more args, default values are used. I don't see any args to pass to your invocation. PS yes, Author=Committer always in my use case, so I don't need the added complexity of handling them separately.

Comment: @DeltaIV I'm suggesting that instead of filtering the repo with multiple passes, you can modify the if statement to do it in a single pass. If you have 100 email addresses to change, you could do 100 passes (plus another for the default), or just have 100 if and elif clauses in the callback. My gut feeling is a single callback will be faster too. (Though `git-filter-repo` is very fast so it probably doesn't matter that much.) The biggest gain I think with my method is how to handle the default case. A single "else" clause may be easier than "if not one of these 100, then use the default".

Comment: There's a misunderstanding. I don't want to change 100 email addresses in the same repo. For different repos, I would like to substitute an email address, `old_email`, which usually depends on the repo, with a new email address (and author), `new_email` and `author`, which are often the same for different repos. That's why I'd like to have a shell script with arguments.

Comment: @DeltaIV oh. That makes sense. Yeah I definitely made an assumption that it was all for one repo rather than a single change for multiple repos. I suppose that clarification could go into the question, since based on the way it's currently written I suspect more people would assume what I did than your actual scenario. That being said, I could have just answered what you asked instead of wrongly assuming this would be even better than what you asked. Hehe.

Comment: No problem! I will edit the question accordingly.